# How to create a Web App project without page.designer.cs files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web, deployment, publish, projects

In Visual Studio 2012 there is no website deployment, ok I switched to Web Project, now it has generated tons of page.designer.cs files, how can I make a web app project without the designer.cs files ?

Comment: I edited the question to make it have a more appropriate tone, the comment from @StingyJack is probably now in need of editing since it's going to be seen as out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio create these files for easiness of coder, you will always get these kind of files when you create a new web app project. These files creates the necessary code you need for designing the web page. 
But once you publish the web app to the server using the VS2010 publisher, these files are gone and only the .aspx files are remained. Why does this happen? because your code i.e. .cs files needs to compiled before it can be published on the server.